# Halo Combat Evolved Rendering Issue

Tags: wine, macbook, playonlinux

I'm trying to run Halo Combat Evolved on my macbook pro running ubuntu using playon linux. It's successfully installed and it plays but the screen is rendered unusably with the a mirror image running 45 degrees diagonally across the screen.

I have mfc42 native and d3d8 bulletin installed in my libraries in my wine configuration.